Permission Denied Error in Databricks Key Vault
com.databricks.common.client.DatabricksServiceHttpClientException: PERMISSION_DENIED: Invalid permissions on the specified KeyVault. Wrapped Message: Status code 403, "{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource.\r\nIf role assignments, deny assignments or role definitions were changed recently, please observe propagation time.\r\nCaller: name=AzureDatabricks;appid=/\r\nAction: 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets/getSecret/action'\r\nResource: '/subscriptions//resourcegroups//providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults//secrets/serviceprincipalid'\r\nAssignment: (not found)\r\nDenyAssignmentId: null\r\nDecisionReason: null \r\nVault: itidevkv2;location=eastus\r\n","innererror":{"code":"ForbiddenByRbac"}}}"
Provide Contributer and KeyVault Reader access to the service principal in Azure key vault. Then created a secret scope in databricks to link the azure key vault.

Is your keyvault RBAC or Access policy ? Is using RBAC, you cannot provide Databricks access to a single secret, you need to provide access to the entire Keyvault.  So provide the Key Vault Administrator role to the Enterprise application called "AzureDatabricks" with application id 2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d

@AnupamChand, resolved. Thanks!


If databricks doesn't have permission to access azure key vault, then you may get above error. To resolve the error Add Key Vault Administrator role to AzureDatabricks Service principle as shown below:
Go to Access control (IAM) of key vault click on Add, Select Add role assignement as shown below:

Select the role and service principle as shown below:

Then you will be able to access key vault secret successfully as shown below:

